# Google Cloud MySQL: No .frm file, Table not in list, no orphans in database schema or temp tables, but table exists/not exists

Tags: mysql, innodb, google-cloud-sql, mysql-python

I've read numerous statoverflow articles and the Google Cloud Help Page but still get this issue:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%#sql%';

Response: []

Query: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE NAME LIKE '%company_metadata%'

Response: [(1155, '<db_name>/company_metadata', 33, 12, 1075, 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', 0, 'Single')]

Query: RENAME TABLE company_metadata TO old_company_metadata

Response: 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './<db_name>/company_metadata.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

Query: select * from company_metadata

Response: There was an error in your query: 
1146 (42S02): Table '<db_name>.company_metadata' doesn't exist

Query: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company_metadata(pk_cometa_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,...)

Response: There was an error in your query: 
1813 (HY000): Tablespace '`<db_name>`.`company_metadata`' exists.
Rolling Back. Please wait...
Roll Back Completed
Disconneting From Database. Please Reconnect Again
```

What I have:
MySQL 5.7
Google Cloud SQL
ENGINE=InnoDB

Where I've been:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
[MySQL clean orphan tables innoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943867/mysql-clean-orphan-tables-innodb)
[Where are my .myd, .myi and .frm files from my mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335834/where-are-my-myd-myi-and-frm-files-from-my-mysql-database)
[MySQL Table does not exist error, but it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260546/mysql-table-does-not-exist-error-but-it-does-exist)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-mysql-table-exists-without-using-select-from-syntax#:~:text=You%20can%20query%20the%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20tables%20system%20view%3A,no%20rows%20returned%2C%20then%20the%20table%20doesn%27t%20exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829102/check-if-mysql-table-exists-without-using-select-from-syntax#:%7E:text=You%20can%20query%20the%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA%20tables%20system%20view%3A,no%20rows%20returned%2C%20then%20the%20table%20doesn%27t%20exist).

P.S. How do I delete this:
[(1155, '<db_name>/company_metadata', 33, 12, 1075, 'Barracuda', 'Dynamic', 0, 'Single')]

I ask because it is the only evidence that my db has given me as evidence of the table existing.

Comment: Try `REPAIR TABLE company_metadata;`

Comment: What ENGINE was the table?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks. It's ENGINE=InnoDB.

Comment: Hi Rick, I still get the same errors After performing the repair. I tried all the queries above and got same responses. Nothing has changed.